# How to install the latest version of nodejs on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

I am trying to install the latest version of nodejs on my laptop using npm. But everytime I try to install, I get this message:

```
npm is known not to run on Node.js v4.2.6
Node.js 4 is supported but the specific version you're running has
a bug known to break npm. Please update to at least 4.7.0 to use this
version of npm. You can find the latest release of Node.js at https://nodejs.org/
```

I have tried all the methods of installing or upgrading nodejs and npm but I get this message everytime. Also, when I run nodejs -v, it shows v4.2.6.

What can I do to install nodejs properly so that I can use it?

Comment: "tried all the methods of installing or upgrading nodejs and npm" what methods were those?

Comment: Such as installing through package manager, using terminal commands as given on the official website etc

Answer (score 2):

Read the error carefully. Node.js 4 is supported but the specific version you're running has **a bug known to break npm**.

You have a nodejs version installed which doesn't let npm run. So you can't use npm to update nodejs. Instead, you can follow nodejs installation guide "Debian and Ubuntu based Linux distributions" from the link https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

for Node.js 6:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Alternatively, for Node.js 8:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: I think I did this earlier too. However, I have followed these steps again. Now, what should I do?

Comment: check the node version in your terminal "node -v" . If it's not updated to v6.x or v8.x then try above command and check if there are errors while installing. If so, try to resolve them.

Answer (score 0):

Try running below command:-

```
# Remove existing Node.js and npm
sudo apt remove nodejs npm
# Install nvm (Node Version Manager)
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

Make sure to close and reopen terminal after running above command and then run below command in your terminal:-

```
nvm install --lts
nvm use --lts
node -v
npm -v
nvm list
nvm alias default <version>
```

When you run nvm list, you will be able to see the list of nodejs version available in your system and then you can replace '' with the LTS version number you installed.

FYI:-

```
nvm alias default <version>
```

This command will set specific nodejs version as default version that will be used globally in all your projects but in case if you want to change it for specific project then just go the path of that specific project in your terminal and use below command

```
nvm use <version>
```

Let me know if it works for you or not.